# references for Hermitian spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am looking for online references for Hermitian forms/Hermitian spaces, on level of advanced undergrad or first year grad. Preferably something a little wordy, hopefully to give insight. A book might be helpful.

For example, this is (for me) a very useful reference to bilinear forms:
https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/bilinearform.pdf.

I did a stack exchange search but could not find anything. Google was a little helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, finding online references on these topics at undergrad/early grad level is a little tricky. In addition to the Conrad notes you linked to, these notes from Berkeley (https://math.berkeley.edu/~gmelvin/math110su12/math110su12notes_p110-119.pdf) are at about that level and appear to be quite good. I also found these notes (http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/diag_11.pdf) on diagonalisation of Hermitian matrices to be very helpful.

As far as books go, believe it or not Hermitian forms are covered pretty well in Artin's *Algebra*, in Chapter 8 (Bilinear forms). There are also many exercises, and since the book is fairly well known, solutions can usually be found online. Another book at graduate level is *Problems and Theorems in Linear Algebra* by V.V. Prasolov. This covers Hermitian forms at a slightly higher level, however many of the results are scattered throughout the text, rather than collected in one single chapter or section. Hopefully you find one or more of these references useful.